# WPF WeakReference builds up memory over time

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, weak-references

I have a WPF application which uses MEF to load some dialogs.
I noticed that after some time it starts to build up more and more WeakReferences which seem to not be freed. The test scenario has a memory pressure item to build up ~3GB. The dialog calls a DataService and reloads the contents of a DataGrid.

What can be the cause for such amount of WeakReferences not being freed?
I cannot see any application specific references being kept.
Below a picture of the memory profiling session with a view on the last added items. Number of WeakReferences added is noticable.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Memory issue]

**UPDATE:**
The profiler I used on a remote computer shows that the build up is mainly caused by new `WeakReference`s. `WaitCallback` is probably beacuse of a loop which I made to elaborate the problem and cause a refresh every second. Otherwise the Objects delta is clean.

[image: Memory profiling]

Comment: Can you make a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this? There's a distinct lack of useful code in your question.

Comment: *"more WeakReferences which seem to not be freed"* - not necessarily the reason. It's totally normal for WPF application to have many of those. You have a typical problem of memory leakage, we can't really help you with it. You can get some hints by searching for "wpf memory leak" (try adding relevant/suspected techonogies, like "mef" you mentioned), typically just get the best profiler for .net you can afford and learn how to use it.

Comment: Making an example will be rather time consuming so I hoped someone already encountered something similar. The domain specific objects seem to be garbage collected. The main addition of references is due to WeakReference. Other objects are <5 instances added. This for me seems weird. The self contained example will probably lead me to an answer in the end. Hopefully when I find the culprit I will inform about it. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: Most of the issues that I have faced with memory leaks were about NOT unsubscribing from methods which cause garbage collector NOT to collect these objects. This would be the first place where I'd look at on your place.